# How do you pass dynamic css classes in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I have an image where the CSS class on the image needs to be change dynamically. It is passed in dynamically from this object from the key "size":

```
export const decals = [
  { label: 'Nikola Tesla', img: `/images/decals/tesla.svg`,  size: `decalMed` },
  { label: 'Tattoo Mom Heart', img: `/images/decals/ARF149.svg`, size: `decalSm`}
```

Into another component here:

```
import styles from ./Shirt.module.css';
<img key={decals[decal].label} src={decals[decal].img} alt={decals[decal].label} className={`${styles}.${decals[decal].size}`}/>
```

The className= is the issue. I've tried so many different ways to pass this class.

I've captured this (decals[decal].size) into a variable before passing to the image tag.
I've tried to use the style tag instead of className and created a variable to hold the class.
I've changed around the brackets. I've tried passing it into an outside div.

Nothing seems to work.

I'm wondering if anyone can clue a react newbie in. Thank you!

Comment: can u provide more info ? cuz i cant figure out what u want to achive

Comment: You can write it like : `className={styles[decals[decal].size]}` because `styles` is just an **object**. See https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#css-modules

Comment: @AjeetShah thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong, you trying to dynamically manage classes that are passing through to the image element.To do that, I recommend you to use "classnames"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

With this package, you can control classNames with variables in your component.
I will try explain usage with a little example.

Your style file like

```
.yourParentClass {
    &.decalMedClass {
        // your styles for this class
    }
    &.decalSmClass {
        // your styles for this class
    }
}
```

your component file like

```
import Style from '../style.scss';   // Your classes
var classNames = require('classnames/bind');  // classname package
const cx = classNames.bind(Style);

// your code
render() {
    return (
        <img className={
            cx({
                yourParentClass: true,
                decalMedClass: this.state.sizeMed,
                decalSmClass: !this.state.sizeMed,
            })
        }
        />
    );
}
```

Basically, you telling that which class gonna be active.
Please do not stick with my example, there are good examples on the npm page.